# Sitecore rich text editor stripping indentation

Tags: sitecore, rtf, sitecore8, rich-text-editor, richtext

When I pretty-format HTML in Sitecore 8, with proper indentation to allow easy maintenance, the Telerik rich text editor apparently strips out the indentation on save (or something else does). Is there some way to disable this automatic whitespace stripping?

Comment: I've just tried to test it on vanilla Sitecore installation and as I can see Sitecore leaves all whitespaces and tabs. Can you provide an example of what HTML you give Sitecore to save and the result after saving?

Comment: Thank you, Aleksey. It's literally any HTML--the only whitespace left in is line breaks. 

Can you reproduce by switching between the WYSIWYG and text view? I've found recently that editing and saving only in the text view preserves formatting, but switching views triggers the unwanted behavior.

Comment: We are having same issue. Can anyone please answer this question? Thanks